# Where am i doing a mistake in malloc?

Tags: arrays, c, char, integer, malloc

I want to convert number X from 'input' number system to 'output' number system and result is save in out. I am using malloc for first time and I do not know how to use it properly. The program works but it return -1073740940 and I do not get any number and result. This function take number if the output system is the same as input it return the same number. Otherwise it start converting. I do not know where is an error. But when I was using `printf("HERE")` to locate an error it was `tab = malloc(N* sizeof(int));` after this command it doesn't work any more. Fill and FIlli functions fill all array in NULL. You have this functions under the conversion. Please help. I need to end this project so fast. I don't have any time. The N is 4000. It's define. I am using scanf to read  this 3 variables than I am `argumentx = malloc(N * sizeof(char));` conversion(input, output, x, argumentx); SO NOBODY KNOWS WHATS WRONG :))))))) THANK YOU

```
void conversion(int input, int output, char* x, char* out)
{  
    int length = strlen(x), which = 0, le, tmp, y, k, first = 0, howmuch = 0, len, len2;
    int *tab, *carry, *end;
    len = length + 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {

        if (x[i] >= '0' && x[i] <= '9')
        {
            if (x[i] - '0' >= input)
            {
                bad = 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (x[i] >= 'A' && x[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            if (x[i] - 'A' >= input)
            {
                bad = 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (x[i] > 'Z')
        {
            bad = 1;
            return;
        }
    }
    if (input == output) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            out[i] = x[i];
        }
        return;
    }
    tab = malloc(N* sizeof(int));
    printf("flaga\n");
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (x[i] >= '0' && x[i] <= '9')
        {
            tab[which++] = (int)(x[i] - '0');
        }
        else
        {
            tab[which++] = 10 + (int)(x[i] - 'A');
        }
    }
    if (length * (input / (output)) > length * (output / (input)))
    {
        le = length * (input / (output));
    }
    else
    {
        le = length * (output / (input));
    }
    len2 = which * le + 3;
    
    carry = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    end = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    filli(len2,carry);
    filli(len2,end);
    carry[0] = 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < which; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < le; j++)
        {
            end[j] += carry[j] * tab[i];
            tmp = end[j];
            y = 0;
            k = j;
            do {
                y = tmp / output;
                end[k] = tmp - y * output;
                k++;
                end[k] += y;
                tmp = end[k];

            } while (tmp >= output);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < le; j++)
        {
            carry[j] = carry[j] * input;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < le; j++)
        {
            tmp = carry[j];
            y = 0;
            k = j;
            do {
                y = tmp / output;
                carry[k] = tmp - y * output;
                k++;
                carry[k] += y;
                tmp = carry[k];
            } while (tmp >= output);
        }
    }
    fill(out);
    tmp = 0;
    first = 0;
    for (int i = le; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (end[i] != 0)
        {
            first = 1;
        }
        if (first == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (end[i] < 10)
        {
            out[tmp] = (char)(end[i] + '0');
            tmp++;
        }
        else
        {
            out[tmp] = (char)(end[i] + 'A' - 10);
            tmp++;
        }

    }
    out[tmp] = out[tmp + 1];
    free(carry);
    free(end);
    free(tab);
    return;
}
void fill(char* x)
{
    int length = strlen(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        x[i] = (char)NULL;
    }
    return;
}
void filli(int length,int* x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        x[i] = (int)NULL;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is `N`? How is the `conversion` function called in the test? Code is incomplete. Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you using `NULL` to assign to `char`s and `int`s? `x[i] = '\0';` and `x[i] = 0;` would seem more appropriate.

Comment: void fill(char* x)
{
    int length = strlen(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        x[i] = '\0';;
    }
    return;
}
void filli(int length,int* x)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
  x[i] = 0;
 }
 return;
}

Comment: but void fill(char*x) is only used to fill(out) and out is char* filli(int* x)

Comment: @kaylum i think fill isnt bad but malloc function doesnt work

Comment: As requested before, please make a [mcve]; you will probably not get an answer otherwise.  The best way for people to find out what's wrong would be to actually compile, test, and run it, with input that makes the problem occur.  It is kind of unreasonable to expect people to spend an hour studying 150 lines of code, when by running it with appropriate debugging tools they could very likely find the problem in two minutes.  (As could you.  Do you know how to use a debugger?  Have you tried tools like valgrind, AddressSanitizer, etc?)

Comment: `I want to convert number X from 'input' number system to 'output' number system` What does it mean. You want to convert number to BASEx string?

Comment: To base output from input

Comment: What your parameters mean?

Comment: Martfosz, `out ` does not point to a _string_ as that data lacks a _null character_.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the task into two functions.

```
static const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnoprqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
unsigned long long fromString(const char *input, const unsigned base)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    if(base > 1 && base <= sizeof(digits))
    {
        while(*input)
        {
            const char *res;
            if(!(res = strchr(digits, *input)) || (res - digits) >= base)
            {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }
            result *= base;
            result += res - digits;
            input++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

char *toString(unsigned long long val, const unsigned base)
{
    size_t length = 1;
    unsigned long long mask = 1, wrk = val;
    char *result = NULL;

    if(base > 1 && base <= sizeof(digits))
    {
        do {++length; mask *= length > 2 ? base : 1;} while(wrk /= base);
        result = malloc(length);
        if(result)
        {
            char *wrkresult = result;
            do
            {
                *wrkresult++ = digits[val / mask];
                val %= mask;
            }while(mask /= base);
            *wrkresult = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

char *fromAtoB(const char *input, const unsigned inputBase, const unsigned outputBase)
{
    return toString(fromString(input, inputBase), outputBase);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s", fromAtoB("255", 10, 16));
}
```

Comment: `toString(0, base)` looks like a problem.  Perhaps `do { ... } while (wrk /= base);`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica indeed, a bit inconsistent first wrong, seconds OK. To late for programming :)

Comment: We all need our beauty sleep.  See you in November.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica :)